# Custom UITableViewCell like bubble

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to customise cell origin x, origin y, width and height.
I want UITableViewCell like this. i want my data in cell like bubble chat
[image]

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: i want to change cell frame custom means every cell has different width and origin x. i want my data in cell like bubble chat

Comment: Simply add custom label or view in tabel view cell and change position

Comment: @NANNAV but not able to looks like bubble chat

Comment: 1) You need cells with custom height based on content.
2) Inside the cell, at least 2 views. One custom image view for the bubble image, and one label.

The bubble should be pretty easy to build using a resizable image.

Comment: @Nik's : Are you looking for chat ?

Comment: @Nik's I know you are new so we are kind, but if you don't want to be downvoted, it would be good you ask a real question in your question, and eventually do some search effort before asking. I'm sure your question is not that hard. And if it is, then you need to explain it better on the first time (not completing it with comment).

Comment: @Nik's ios not have bubble chat you only coustomize view for bubble using image or other

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Might be you are looking for below custom UITableView and source code;

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/scroller
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/animated-tableviewcell
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/stbubbletableviewcell
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ptsmessagingcell
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/jsmessagesviewcontroller
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/sphchatbubble

Use and edit it as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

For chating using the custom classes of PTSMessagingCell
Here you can customize your images and other controls.

Catch the sample code [PTSMessagingCell-master](https://github.com/ppanopticon/PTSMessagingCell/)

Answer (score 0):

Create custom view that as per your requirement and them create your custom `UItableViewCell`.

Add your custom view in cell contentview under the following method:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString*)reuseIdentifier
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Using a background image for the cell: one image for cell left and another for right cell.
2. Change the text label's frame.
3. Set the background cell color `clearColor`
4. Set the separator style `none`.

This is basically what your are looking for. Then you have to optimize the UI, for example for calculate the bubble height.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend you to use customzed `UIs`. You can easily plugin data and display `text` and `images`. These `UIs` save days after days of work. Here are two great `UIs` for `objective-c` and `swift`. They are both open sourced and on github.

Objective-C:
https://github.com/AlexBarinov/UIBubbleTableView

Swift:
https://github.com/badoo/Chatto